# Custom struct interacted with as if it were an int?

Tags: c++, struct, constants, custom-operator

I'm trying to create a structure that can be interacted with as if it were an `int`. However, when I try to assign a value to it, it throws the following error upon compiling:

```
Invalid conversion from `int` to `int32*`
```

Why does it throw that error, even though I made it's `=` operator to handle setting an `int32` to a `const int` value?

Here's the source code for my best attempt at `int32`:

```
struct int32
{
  int32_t val;

  int32(int val=0)
    : val(val)
  {
  }

  int32& operator=(const int value) // ex. int32 *i = 42;
  {
    val=value;
    return *this;
  }
  int32 operator+(const int32& value) const
  {
    return int32(value.val+val);
  }
  int32 operator-(const int32& value) const
  {
    return int32(value.val-val);
  }
  int32 operator*(const int32& value) const
  {
    return int32(value.val*val);
  }
  int32 operator/(const int32& value) const
  {
    return int32(value.val/val);
  }
  int32 operator%(const int32& value) const
  {
    return int32(value.val%val);
  }
  bool operator==(const int32& value) const
  {
    return (val == value.val);
  }
  bool operator!=(const int32& value) const
  {
    return (val != value.val);
  }
}
```

Also, please don't just recommend I use `int32_t`; I'm making my own `struct` for a reason (otherwise I'd have just used `int32_t` to begin with ;)

Comment: Avoid pointers. `int32*` is the source of trouble (not shown here)

Comment: Any reason you're using `int32*` and not `int32`?

Comment: You need to post the code that causes the error.

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm using pointers because I'm integrating this code with my personal garbage collector (I've not gotten to test this struct with it, because I haven't even gotten the struct itself to work properly)

Comment: Did you mean to write `int32 i = 42;` instead of `int32 *i = 42;`?

Comment: @JosephCaruso I'm not sure why that would matter from a GC perspective - if you mean to allocate it locally, you should just allocate it locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by your comments, you're doing this:

```
int32 *i = 42;
```

You're trying to assign the value 42 to a pointer, which won't work here.  Drop the `*` and call your constructor instead:

```
int32 i(42);
```

If you need a pointer to that object, you can then simply take its address:

```
int32 my_int32(42);
int32 *i = &my_int32;
```

If you have a pointer to an existing `int32` object, and want to assign a new value to the object, you can dereference the pointer:

```
int32 *i = ...;
*i = 42;
```

Comment: I tried replacing `int32 *i = 42;` with `int32 *i; &i = 42;` and it still won't work. New error: `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

Comment: @JosephCaruso I think you need to lean about pointers then come back to this problem.

Comment: @EldarDordzhiev I was trying to avoid using the new operator (I wanted the int32 "i" to die with the stack as a normal int would, but I guess I can modify the garbage collector to handle that.

Comment: Ohhh well there's my problem, I went stupid and put &i instead of *i to deterrence i... (Facepalm)

Comment: @JosephCaruso `int32 *i; *i = 42;` will not work either. If you want the `int32` to be on the stack, then *just put it on the stack* instead of messing around with pointers. `int32 i = 42;`. Done.

Comment: @immibis Now I'm really facepalming... Yep, that fixed the problem... Such a novice mistake XD Thanks, it compiles now :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> int32 *i = 42;
> ```

is a problem since you are trying to initialize a `int32*` with the number `42`.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
int32 i = 42;
```

However, that would invoke the constructor, not the assignment operator.

To invoke the assignment operator, use:

```
int32 i;
i = 42;
```

Comment: It specifically needs to be an `int32 *`... Would this require I edit `int32`?

Comment: @JosephCaruso If you need a pointer, just construct it normally and take its address: `int32 my_int32(42); int32 *i = &my_int32;`

Comment: @JosephCaruso You'll notice that `int *i = 42;` doesn't work either. How would you do whatever you're trying to do if you were using a normal `int` instead of an `int32`?